# Trying Fetch Picklist values Of Oppourtunites dynamcially in VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist

[image]

I am trying to fetch picklist values in VF page.But it is displaying in wierd way.Please find the screenshot.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CreateOppExtension">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="save">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>

      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Information" columns="2">
          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Opportunity_Type__c}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Start_Date__c}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>

          <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.PM_I_Business_Field__c}" size="1" style="width:400px" >
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeOptions}"/>                  

                            </apex:selectList> 

          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Main_Group_GPH1__c}"/>

          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Product__c}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.USP__c}"/>


          <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.Process_Quadrant__c}" multiselect="false" size="1">
               <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Protect Base/Manage Needs" itemLabel="Protect Base/Manage Needs"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Grow Share/New Products" itemLabel="Grow Share/New Products"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Replace Competitors/Deliver Unmet Needs" itemLabel="Replace Competitors/Deliver Unmet Needs"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="New Markets/What-If Innovation" itemLabel="New Markets/What-If Innovation"/>
          </apex:selectList>

            <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.Customer_Group_ERP__c}" id="customer" size="1" multiselect="false">
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>   
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="SAMSUNG" itemLabel="SAMSUNG"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="SAE MAGNETICS" itemLabel="SAE MAGNETICS"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="MICRON GROUP" itemLabel="MICRON GROUP"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="TOSHIBA" itemLabel="TOSHIBA"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="TSMC" itemLabel="TSMC"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="INTEL" itemLabel="INTEL"/>     
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="GLOBALFOUNDRIES" itemLabel="GLOBALFOUNDRIES"/>    
                   <apex:selectOption itemValue="NANYA" itemLabel="NANYA"/> 
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="POWERCHIP" itemLabel="POWERCHIP"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="WINBOND" itemLabel="WINBOND"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="UMC" itemLabel="UMC"/>   
                  <apex:selectOption itemValue="Others" itemLabel="Others"/>  
                  </apex:selectList> 

            <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.Device__c}">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeCG}"/>                  
                   </apex:selectList>  




          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.TopProject__c}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="References" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Master_Account__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.R_D_Project__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Project_ID__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.NBD_ID__c}"/>                        
             </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Sales Cycle" columns="2">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Status__c}"/>

               <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.Reason_PM_I__c}" multiselect="false" size="1">
               <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Quality" itemLabel="Quality"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Service" itemLabel="Service"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Price" itemLabel="Price"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Other" itemLabel="Other"/>
          </apex:selectList>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.Sub_Reason__c}"> 
                      <apex:selectOptions value="{!subreason}"/>
          </apex:selectList>

                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Probability}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Exp_Sales_Vol_p_a_EUR__c}"/>  
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Expected_Rev_rHVM__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.PMI_In_Forecast__c}"/>

                   <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.Main_Group_GPH1__c}">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeDevice}"/>                  
                   </apex:selectList> 

                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Counter_Measures__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Price_EUR_Unit__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Dispense_Volume_mUnit__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Layers__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Unit__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.R_D_Headcount__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Notes" columns="1">
          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Notes__c}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Marketing_Notes__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex controller:

```
public class CreateOppExtension 
{

    Opportunity opp {get;set;}
    ApexPages.StandardController GstdController;
     public CreateOppExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
     {   
        GstdController= stdController;
        opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        opp.Notes__c = 'Testing';
    }

       public List<SelectOption> getTypeOptions()
       {


           List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
           options.add(new SelectOption('None','--None--'));
           Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.PM_I_Business_Field__c.getDescribe();
           List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
           for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : ple)
               options.add(new SelectOption(p.getLabel(), p.getValue())); 
           return options;


       }
     public List<SelectOption> getsubreason()
       {


           List<SelectOption> reasons = new List<SelectOption>();
           reasons.add(new SelectOption('None','--None--'));
           Schema.DescribeFieldResult sub = Opportunity.Sub_Reason__c.getDescribe();
           List<Schema.PicklistEntry> reason = sub.getPicklistValues();
           for(Schema.PicklistEntry S : reason)
               reasons.add(new SelectOption(S.getLabel(), S.getValue())); 
           return reasons;


       }
       public List<SelectOption> getTypeCG()
       {
           List<SelectOption> cglist = new List<SelectOption>();
           cglist.add(new SelectOption('None','--None--'));
           Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Opportunity.Device__c.getDescribe();
           List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick = f.getPicklistValues();
           for(Schema.PicklistEntry b: pick)
               cglist.add(new SelectOption(b.getLabel(), b.getValue())); 
           return cglist;
     }

     public List<SelectOption> getTypeDevice()
       {
            List<SelectOption> dev = new List<SelectOption>();
           dev.add(new SelectOption('None','--None--'));
           Schema.DescribeFieldResult d = Opportunity.Main_Group_GPH1__c.getDescribe();
           List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick = d.getPicklistValues();
           for(Schema.PicklistEntry J: pick)
               dev.add(new SelectOption(J.getLabel(), J.getValue())); 
           return dev;
     }


     public PageReference save(){
        insert opp;
        return ApexPages.currentPage();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display only one value of picklist use `size="1"`. To disable multi-select add `multiselect="false"`

```
<apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.Sub_Reason__c}" multiselect="false" size="1> 
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!subreason}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: Thank you @ Alexander Berehovskiy It worked,But there are field dependencies between Reason --> Subreason ,Customer group ERP and Device picklist values. I have fetched these values dynamically. Field Dependency is NOT working in this VF page.Please help